# Error converting raster to vector when creating heat maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, heatmap, qgis

Using QGIS 3.4.1-Madeira, Python 3.6, Mac 10.14.1 Mojave

I am trying to create heatmaps to establish the most popular streets on my map. I am following these guidelines: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

At point 17, when I need to convert raster to vector I keep getting the same error message, however this doesn't mean anything to me.[Raster to vector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X69QV.png)

I have done some trouble shooting by checking I have Python 3.6 and following these steps to find the correct libraries: http://www.kyngchaos.com/2018/04/06/qgis-3-tools-processing-workaround/ When I go to libraries>frameworks as the value suggests, there is no frameworks folder there. Am I looking in the wrong place? [Finder>Go>alt>libraries]

This process a key part of my data analysis. Is there another work around (that doesn't involve code - I'm not that advanced) or another plug in? Or is this a bug with Madeira? Am I doing something incorrectly? I'm not sure what else to check.